# wordpress get id from param given route format. define and change hook

Tags: wordpress

Given an API route for retrieving a specific record, do the following:

1. Get the id param
2. Return a 404 if the record isn't found
3. Return a response with the record if it is found

Route format:

```
/publishers/(?P<id>\d+)`
/publishers/397
```

Code that returns the response:

```php
<?php

function get_publisher( \WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    $publisher_id = null; // get the id parameter

    // imagine code that gets the record from the database
    if ( empty( $publisher ) ) {
        // return a 404 response
    }

    // return a normal response with the `$publisher`
}
```

Then add a `WordPress hook` to determine the value of the visible property on some item. Then use that hook elsewhere to change the value to false;

```php
<?php

function modify_item( $item ) {
    // item is an object
    // set the `visible` property to the value of a hook `item_visibility`, with a default value of `true`

    return $item;
}

// elsewhere...
function hide_item() {
    // use the `item_visibility` hook to change the item's visibility to `false`
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What's the question?

Comment: Thank You! Its homework, there are a few parts:Given an API route for retrieving a specific record, do the following:

Get the id param
Return a 404 if the record isn't found
Return a response with the record if it is found Then add a WordPress hook to determine the value of the visible property on some item. Then use that hook elsewhere to change the value to false;

Comment: While Stack Overflow is a good resource, we aren't here to do your homework. You are expected to try and accomplish whatever the issue it is, and come here to ask a specific question where you are stuck. As it stands, this question is way too broad.